# How to merge two dataframe based on multiple criteria plus id

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge

Here's my dataframe `df`

```
Id     Value
3      104
6      108
```

Here's the reference data `ref`

```
Id    Code  Long     Lat
1     ABC     89      82
2     DEF     87      81
3     GHI     89      82
4     IJK     90      81
5     LMN     90      81
6     OPQ     87      81
```

Here's what I did

```
df.merge(ref, how='left', left_on=['Id'], right_on = ['Id'])
```

The Result is

```
Id     Value    Code    Long     Lat
3      104      GHI       89      82
6      108      OPQ       87      81
```

What I expect is
`Id` `1` is give `Value` `104`, because it has same `Long` and `Lat` with `Id` `3` ,
`Id` `2` is give `Value` `108`, because it has same `Long` and `Lat` with `Id` `6`

So the output dataframe going to be like this

```
Id     Value    Code    Long     Lat
1      104      ABC       89      82
2      108      DEF       87      81
3      104      GHI       89      82
6      108      OPQ       87      81
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do merge twice

```
temp = df.merge(ref, how='left', left_on=['Id'], right_on = ['Id'])
out = ref.merge(temp[['Value','Long','Lat']])
Out[473]: 
   Id Code  Long  Lat  Value
0   1  ABC    89   82    104
1   3  GHI    89   82    104
2   2  DEF    87   81    108
3   6  OPQ    87   81    108
```